# Should a bidirectional iterator having reached end remain decrementable in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, standards, bidirectional

I'm writing a special iterator class that works like `std::istream_iterator` and many others by using a default-constructed instance to mark end of iteration. I want to give it the bidirectional iterator category. After running the following code:

```
MyIterType i_cur(get_some_iter()), i_end;
while(i_cur != i_end) ++i_cur;
```

do the standard requirements for bidirectional iterators impose the following to be valid?

1. `--i_cur`
2. `++i_cur`
3. `--i_end` or `++i_end`

Thank you for quoting the standard if possible. I compile in C++03, but if C++11 introduces changes, I'm also interested to know them.

Comment: I haven't checked the spec., but if [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) is anything to go by then you should be able to decrement both iterators even if they are at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but in my understanding, it only means operators ++ and -- must be available, not that they should have defined behavior when called on any instance. Or do you think that the note for expression "++i" in [the ForwardIterator part of the concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) indicates that calling ++i has not made the program crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard says that the answer to your question is yes:

### [C++03] : 24.1.4 Bidirectional iterators

```
Table 75—Bidirectional iterator requirements (in addition to forward iterator)

   expression    return type    operational    assertion/note
                                semantics    pre/post-coindition
   ========      ============   ============ ====================
   --r             X&                         pre: there exists s such
                                              that r == ++s.
                                              post: s is dereferenceable.
                                              --(++r) == r.
                                              --r == --s implies r
                                              == s.
                                              &r == &--r
```

Comment: Thank you for the 2003 standard quotation.

Answer (score 1):

In 24.2.6 in C++11, Table 110 gives the additional requirements for a bidirectional iterator.

In particular, if there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`, then `--r` must be valid and the resulting `r` must be dereferenceable.  In addition:

- `--(++r) == r`.
- `--r == --s` implies `r == s`.
- `&r == &--r`.

So unless the initial `i_cur` returned by `get_some_iter` is a past-the-end iterator, the final `i_cur` has a predecessor and so must be decrementable.  The same holds for `i_end`, since it is the successor of the predecessor of the final `i_cur`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the standard reference. Do you know whether this applies in C++03?